# Jquery Fast image switching

Tags: php, jquery, image

I have a php class that generates a map image depending on my db data. It is periodically updated thru a serInterval loop.

I am trying to update it with no flickering but I just can't. I've tried different methods (preloader, imageswitcher) with no success.

```
//first load

function map()  {

$("#map").html("<img src=map.php?randval="+Math.random()+">");
}


//update it from setInterval calls

function updatemap()  {

$("#map").fadeOut(function() { 
      $(this).load(function() { $(this).fadeIn(); }); 
      $(this).attr("src", "map.php?randval="+Math.random()); 
    })
 }
```

Is there any way to update the image with no flickering at all? I would prefer an inmediate swap insteado of a fade.

The problem I'm having is that after calling updatemap() the image just dissapears. ¿Maybe it is a problem with the attribute src I am parsing?

THanks for your help.

Comment: Without being able to test the app in question, I'm confused by what you're disliking about it. Could you please either provide a link to the app or more description on what activity you are trying to quash? "Flickering," for me, doesn't give enough detail.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Just edited the question to show which is the problem I am having. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may still get a very slight flicker.

```
function updatemap() {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
        $("#map img").attr("src", img.src);
    }
    img.src = "map.php?randval="+Math.random();
}
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly. No flicker, inmediate update of the image with a few lines. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the subsequent maps into a hidden element first.  Then when they're loaded, swap them in.

```
<div id = "map"></div>
<img id = "load-map" src = "" alt = "" />

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#map").html("<img src=map.php?randval="+Math.random()+">");
   setTimeout(loadImage,5000);
}

function loadImage()
{
  $("#load-map")
    .attr('src','map.php?randVal='+Math.random())
    .load(function(){
      $("#map img").src($("#load-map").src);
      setTimeOut(loadImage,5000);
    });
}
```

Comment: I think there may be a type on the <img id = "load-map" ...> since it is closed with a </div> tag. Tested anyway and it messes up my divs. Tries with <div id ="load-map" ... > but didn't work. Could you please check it? Thanks